# How to assign a derived class object to a base class pointer using a function (not the constructor)

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

**Problem summary**
I don't know how to create an object of a derived class with the new-operator through a function (not a constructor), and have a base class pointer point to it.

**Setup**
I have an abstract base class and a derived class in my project:

```
class Base
{
    // stuff
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    //stuff
    //constructor:
    Derived(args);
};
```

I also have function that returns a `Derived` object.

```
Derived func(args);
```

At some point, I declare a base class pointer

```
Base* ptr = { nullptr };
```

and I want it to point to a `Derived` object later-on.

**What I want**
I want to create a `Derived` object using `func`, and be able to access it through the pointer `ptr` later in the code.

**What I did so far**
I know that it works to use the derived class's constructor

```
ptr = new Derived(args);
```

or simply its default constructor, if it exists

```
ptr = new Derived;
```

However, I have good reasons why I cannot use the constructor in my case, since the configuration of the derived object is more complicated. In this case I want to create this object with the function `func`.

I know that this,

```
ptr = new func(args);
```

does not work, since `new` expects a type. How can I achieve a behavior like this?

Thanks in advance for any advice and helpful replies.

**Note:** I'm using `new` since I need to access the `Derived` object also outside the scope of its creation.

Comment: Can you rewrite `func` such that it returns `Derived*` instead of `Derived`? If so, don't forget to make destructor of `Base` _virtual_. You can also write `Derived d = func(args); ptr = &Derived;`, just it's kind-of fragile, since `d` must then outlive any dereferencing of `ptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. The problem is indeed that ```d``` will not outlive the pointer, which is why I used ```new``` so far.

Comment: Then, use `new` inside `func` and return the obtained pointer. Alex' answer shows the way.

Comment: Return a pointer from `func` might be the best option, but if you cannot modify `func` then `ptr = new Derived(func(args))` might work.

Comment: You could also use `boost::make_shared<Derived>` or `std::make_shared<Derived>` inside `func` and not worry about object lifetime, if the rest of your code permits use of smart pointers, and if `func` is allowed to be written this way by your spec.

Comment: @Mestkon This might be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I guess Mestkon's reply requires the definition of a copy constrictor right?

Comment: @DNT Thanks, I will check out make_shared. I haven't used smart pointers yet.

Comment: @user157765 Either copy costructor or move constructor

Comment: @user157765 Ok, then you might want to look into writing your func as `template<T, TA> boost::shared_ptr<T> func(TA args) { return boost::make_shared<T>(args); }` if you want to generalize it for any compatible class and argument types. You may also want to typedef the shared pointer for better readability.

Comment: @DNT Why `boost::shared_ptr`? Why not `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @DanielLangr No particular reason. I simply chose one of the two to write the example. Actually `std::shared_ptr` will not require any inclusion of boost headers, so it might be preferable depending on requirements.

Comment: @DNT All right. I use Boost a lot, but always would prefer Standard library not to bring into code additional dependency if not needed.

Comment: I don't use boost in this project, so I will checkout the standard library version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a pointer from `func` might be the best option, but if you cannot modify `func` then `ptr = new Derived(func(args))` might work. This requires that `Derived` has a copy constructor or a move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Derived * func(args)
{
  Derived *p = new Derived();
  // do your custom stuff:
  p->x = args->i;
  p->y = 3;

  // return the pointer
  return p;
}

// ...

ptr = func(args);
```

Dont forget to delete ptr later. To be able to call the destructor of Derived, using the pointer to Base later, you have to make the destructor virtual.

```
class Base
{
  // ...
  virtual ~Base();
};
```

Comment: I can modify ```func```, so this might work. It is not what I had in mind for the return value of the function, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into writing your func as

`template<class T, class TA>
boost::shared_ptr<T> func(TA args) { return boost::make_shared<T>(args); }`

or

`template<class T, class TA>
std::shared_ptr<T> func(TA args) { return std::make_shared<T>(args); }`

if you want to generalize it for any compatible class and argument types. You may also want to typedef the shared pointer for better readability.
The shared pointer will also take care of object lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution summary

First of all, thanks to everyone who responded. The advice came incredibly fast and was very helpful and instructive.

I don't know if this is against some convention, but since there were multiple very different solutions, I would like to summarize them. (If I should rather put this as an edit to the question, please let me know).

All three solutions should work, and I use solution 2 for now. However, I might switch to solution 3 after learning more about smart pointers.

### Solution 1 - by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13568225/alex) and [Daniel Langr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580083/daniel-langr)

[[link to reply]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61908579/13381793)

Changing the function `func` such that it returns a pointer.

```
Derived* func(args)
{
    Derived *p = new Derived();
    // do some complicated configuration
    return p;
}
```

Afterwards, I can use the function to directly define the pointer `ptr`.

```
ptr = func(args);
```

Alex also made some important remarks about how to delete the `ptr` later.

While this works very well, I chose not to follow this path, since I would like to avoid changing the return value of `func`.

### Solution 2 - by [Mestkorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9545074/mestkon)

[[link to reply]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61908860/13381793)

Use the copy constructor.

This is maybe the simplest solution. By using the copy constructor, I can simply write

```
    ptr = new Derived( func(args) );
```

While this requires a copy/move constructor, it worked perfectly well with the default copy constructor in my project. I didn't have to implement anything new. This is the solution I have in my code for now.

### Solution 3 - by [DNT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763310/dnt)

[[link to reply]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61909121/13381793)

Use smart pointers, more specifically a `shared_ptr` (Either `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`.) This concept is completely new to me. Thanks for that!

I will learn more about this and might switch to this option, since it sounds like a *cleaner* solution. If I understand correctly, the advantage over the other two solutions is that I don't have to think about memory leakage or deleting the pointer.
Once I figured this out properly, I will come back and extend this summary.